# Авторизация ВК через lynx

Tags: linux, bash, debian, вконтакте, curl

1. ОС Debian.
2. Lynx Version 2.8.9dev.16 (11 Jul 2017)

Заранее прошу прощения за быть может глупые вопросы, но есть цель - залогиниться в свой ВК аккаунт через lynx.
На этой же машине выполнен вход в ВК в Firefox'е (кука лежит и пускает без пароля).
Не разбираюсь в данной теме вовсе, но может есть возможность подменить Юзер-Агента и "спереть" фаерфоксовскую куку(вроде позволяет lynx подгружать левые куки) ну или в лоб как-нибудь передать lynx'у логин и пароль и попасть внутрь?
UPD. Немного поигравшись, ВК теперь редиректит на страницу 'https://vk.com/badbrowser.php', на которой любезно сообщает что ему нужна поддержка Cookies и JS. Cookie вроде поддерживает lynx (-accept_all_cookies), а вот JS судя по всему - нет.
Вопрос все тот же.
Могу лишь расширить диапазон приемлемых решений до - "Как попасть внутрь, используя **ЛЮБОЙ** текстовый(консольный) браузер под Линукс?"

Comment: попробуй мобильную версию m.vk.com - вроде работает без js

Comment: Или elinks, или links2 имел зачаточную поддержку JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://vk.com/hack3d_home
тут ребята пилят консольный клиент ВК под линукс, может подойдет?

Comment: Может, и подойдёт, только ответом на конкретно этот вопрос не является

Comment: Вы просто упомянули продукт без примера его использования в данной ситуации, что похоже на саморекламу. Ещё, из [списка тревог на сообщения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1fCn.png): «*спам* — Рекламирует продукт или услугу, не раскрывая при этом причастность автора.» **Какова ваша причастность к упомянутому вами проекту?**

Comment: Мельком посмотрел функционал и гитхаб - неплохая штука, но чутка другие, конечно, цели я преследовал. Тем не менее, спасибо, интересный проект.

Comment: У меня не возникало задачи пользоваться вк в консоли, но знаю что есть софт, позволяющий это сделать. Никакого отношения к проекту я не имею.